# Aplicate a complex operation on a column to create a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe that looks like the the following, lets call it DF

| Symbol | Date | volume | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2014-01-01 | 1 | 5 |
| A | 2014-01-02 | 3 | 8 |
| A | 2014-01-03 | 7 | 4 |
| A | 2014-01-07 | 3 | 6 |
| A | 2014-01-08 | 34 | 7 |
| A | 2014-01-09 | 45 | 34 |
| A | 2014-01-10 | 4 | 5 |
| A | 2014-01-11 | 9 | 7 |
| A | 2014-01-14 | 8 | 6 |
| A | 2014-01-15 | 4 | 4 |
| A | 2014-01-16 | 0 | 7 |
| A | 2014-01-17 | 4 | 7 |

I want to apply the next operation to the price column:

```
diff(log(DF$price))
```

And generate a datafra like this:

| Date | returns |
| --- | --- |
| 2014-01-01 | 4 |
| 2014-01-02 | 6 |
| 2014-01-03 | 8 |
| 2014-01-07 | 2 |
| 2014-01-08 | 14 |
| 2014-01-09 | 5 |
| 2014-01-10 | 1 |
| 2014-01-11 | 2 |
| 2014-01-14 | 8 |
| 2014-01-15 | 4 |
| 2014-01-16 | 0 |
| 2014-01-17 | 4 |

(The numbers, in the column returns i the examples not are the desired one, are just random numbers that i put to ilustrate, i need that in each row of that column appears the correspondent result of `diff(log(DF$price)`))

I tried the next lines of code but it did not result:

```
Ret <- DF %>% group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(Ret_i = diff(log(DF$price)))%>%
  summarise(Ret_i)
```

Thanks for reading and I would apreciate any help

Comment: I know you're trying to use `diff()`, but conceptually what are you trying to do?  `diff()` will find the difference between adjacent entries in a vector, but in the data you post, there is only one observation per group.

Comment: I´m trying to create a data frame with the date and the logarithmic returns definided as log(p_t)-log(p_t-1).

Comment: OK, then using `group_by(date)` probably doesn't make much sense because you would then be calculating differences within dates rather than across them.  What about something like `DF %>% group_by(Symbol) %>% mutate(Ret_i = log(price)- lag(log(price)))` The `summarise()` statement wasn't doing anything really.  If you wanted mean of returns by `Symbol`, you could add `summarise(Ret = mean(Ret_i, na.rm=TRUE))` after the `mutate()` function.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, I did that and I got the logaritmic returns, but the other column is symbol, wich is equal for every row, and what I need is the columns of the dates. It is very important.

Comment: Then just don’t use the summarise part of the function.